# Can HAProxy respond with a specific sub domain that represents a backend server?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Say someone makes an HTTP get/post request to api.example.com/a/b

Now say I have ten servers setup as my backend servers.

I want a proxy to act as a load balancer, and during the request, handshake responds with:

```
apiX.example.com/a/b
```

where X is a number in the range 1..10

If `HAProxy` isn't the right tool for this, what would you suggest?

What benefits to hardware-based load balancers offer?

**Update**

Generally, from what I understand of proxies is that `HAProxy` will take a request, and proxy it to a backend server, wait for the response, and then send the answer to the client.  The client has no idea which backend server responded to their request.

Now, if I have ten backend servers, the `HAProxy` server will be overloaded since it will have to handle the throughput of 10 servers traffic/bandwidth since all requests and responses are going through the `HAProxy` server.

I am curious if `HAProxy` could hand off the request to a particular backend server, and then the client will talk directly with the backend server (the backend will be publicly accessible at api3.example.com or api[1..10].example.com)

The client will be making only a single request, so the session will last for a single application only where the client makes an HTTP get/post request and waits for a response, that's it.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I'm not sure that I get your proposition.

Comment: @MarceloBittencourt i've updated my question.

Comment: It may be possible, in the first hit the chosen server can create a redirect (302) to himself, and all the conversation later is direct to the server. But I don't think that you can overload haproxy so easily. My main HAProxy gets 11mi hits/day , and it's running in a single proc VPS server with only 1G RAM

Comment: @MarceloBittencourt but if clients are uploading files that are 20-50kb in size, that is allot of data going through a single server no?

Comment: I believe that it can handle it. near half of my 11mi hits are images, and some other static content. did you know that Stack Exchange uses HAProxy? http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/09/30/the-stack-exchange-architecture-2011-edition-episode-1/

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible or not depending on your setup. If your clients are configured to use a proxy server (which is HAproxy) or you are always transparently proxying all requests to HAproxy, then apparently your idea can not be implemented.

On the other hand, if the name api.example.com points to Haproxy host itself. You can use `redirect` to send 302 HTTP codes to your clients. The redirects should point to one of the backend servers. Then, you need to find a way to use different `redirect` statements for different backend servers based on some criteria. You can choose something changing randomly such as source port or source IP.

Comment: Yes api.example.com will point to haproxy itself, and yes I will distribute load (initially) doing round robin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having your backend servers append a header with their own header with server id/host name in the response?

Update 10/8/12: HAProxy 1.4.20 added an option http-send-name-header, which adds the backend server as a hostname on responses.